# Multiple timeseries in TimescaleDB using Django as framework

Tags: django, postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

I'm trying to setup multiple timeseries in timescaledb. The issue comes with different records have the same timestamp, for example

```
from django.db import models
from timescale.db.models.models import TimescaleModel
from .assets import Asset  

class TimeseriesData(TimescaleModel):
    time = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    close_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    volume = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('time', 'asset'),)  # Create a composite unique constraint
```

I might have different assets with the same time, and timescaledb requires time to be the primary key, so how can I work around this? It feels bad practice to create a new timescalemodel for each asset, is this how timescaledb suppose to be used?

I tried adding an id column as a primary key but it fails as timescaledb requires time to be the pk, I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Timescale doesn't require time to be a primary key. What it will required is that you include the partition dimension, in this case the `time` column, in every unique index/constraint. Also, when creating a hypertable, an index on `time` will be created automatically.

According to the [django-timescaledb docs](https://github.com/jamessewell/django-timescaledb?tab=readme-ov-file#django-timescaledb), the `TimescaleModel` is defined as:

```py
  class TimescaleModel(models.Model):
    """
    A helper class for using Timescale within Django, has the TimescaleManager and
    TimescaleDateTimeField already present. This is an abstract class it should
    be inheritted by another class for use.
    """
    time = TimescaleDateTimeField(interval="1 day")

    objects = TimescaleManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Which already includes the `time` definition as a time field, and will define a chunk size of 1 day. You can read more about hypertables and how they are partirtioned into chunks, in the [Timescale docs](https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/hypertables/about-hypertables/#time-partitioning)

In your case, you just need to change your code to:

```py
from django.db import models
from timescale.db.models.models import TimescaleModel
from .assets import Asset  

class TimeseriesData(TimescaleModel):
    asset = models.ForeignKey(Asset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    close_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    volume = models.BigIntegerField()
    
class Meta:
        unique_together = (('time', 'asset'),)  # Create a composite unique constraint
```

As a side note, in most cases you'd want the `time` column to be the last column of the index. From the [Timescale docs on indexing data](https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/schema-management/about-indexing/)

> A good rule of thumb with indexes is to think in layers. Start by choosing the columns that you typically want to run equality operators on, such as location = garage. Then finish by choosing columns you want to use range operators on, such as time > 0930.